# pandas to_hdf() overflow warning

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, hdf5

I need to save a large dataframe to hdf5 file so I used:

```
self.feature_concated.to_hdf(self.h5_result_name, key='feature_data', mode='a', format='table')
```

And a runtimeWarning will show up:

```
F:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tables\leaf.py:357: RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in long_scalars
```

`expected_mb = (expectedrows * rowsize) // MB`

But when I don't use flexible format hdf, it will not have such problem.

```
self.feature_concated.to_hdf(self.h5_result_name, key='feature_data', mode='a')
```

I'm wondering what is the cause of this problem and how could I solve it?

Comment: Is anyone there could answer my question?

Comment: This warning is surely problematic because expected_mb > 2^31. Have you tried to enter in debug mode to trace your problem. When you say large dataframe could you be more specific (structure, size)

Answer (score 0):

Well, I had received the same message when saving a pandas dataframe:

```
RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in long_scalars expected_mb = (expectedrows * rowsize) // MB
```

I have solved it setting dtypes of numeric columns:

```
df_book[["year","bnumber","cnumber","vnumber"]] = \
    df_book[["year","bnumber","cnumber","vnumber"]].apply(pd.to_numeric)
```

In my case I know the types previously.